# Install Grub2 UEFI Fat32 to EFI - No Linux OS

Tags: grub2, boot-loader

Ok, so usually (correct me if I am wrong), but when you install Grub, part of it gets installed inside the Linux OS. /etc/default/grub or /etc/init.d/grub etc etc.

My Goal is to get Grub2 to be my bootloader for Windows and have the config files inside the MBR and edit them from windows.

So How can I load a LinuxLiveCD Ubuntu/Kali preferred OS. Install Grub2 UEFI (and all config files) to mbr(? not sure if that is correct term) or "boot partiton" and have it find Windows, also preferably unhide itself (grub menu) until I have tested/configured it.

I think I need to manually create a boot partition with Gparted and give it boot flag for it to show up in windows., but then I need to still make ti work.

*I think my terminology may be a bit off... to simplyfy:*

I want to turn on my computer and see grub and have only one boot option, Windows 10. (and have no other OS installed on the HD)

Comment: this question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. UEFI specifies a GPT formatted esp - which includes an MBR, but its a dummy because the MBR was always *dumb*. I think you just don't understand what you want, and probably what you already have. If its a UEFI system, then you don't want a bootloader - UEFI *includes* one in the firmware, and bootloaders only ever existed in the first place because MBR is *dumb*.

Comment: The UEFI version of GRUB doesn't go in the MBR, it goes in the EFI system partition.  The MBR isn't involved in UEFI booting at all.

Comment: If you are using Windows 8 or later, you are almost certainly already UEFI booting Windows from a FAT32 filesystem located  in the ESP (EFI System Partition).  This is where you would install GRUB2 and where GRUB2's configuration file would reside, i.e. /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: @fpmurphy1 That is exactly what I want help with, and I knew MBR was the wrong term, hence the ?. But "Master Boot Record" sure sounds like the right words. Anyway, I have a Clevo (brand laptop) with 0 bloatware (don't think i have UEFI firmware settings, its just BIOS) a UEFI set up/booting Windows 10 education x64 and unlocked Prema Bios. Can you direct me to installing grub 2 the Fat32 EFI partition? Everytime I install Grub2 via LiveCD (I install the OS then delete it, it installs grub inside the OS and breaks when I delete OS)

Answer (score -1):

Best way to edit the grub 2 is from within terminal in linux. 1st thing is to mount your partition that the grub was installed from.  Got to a terminal and type sudo gedit  
PASSWORD

This should bring up a grub editor window.  Navigate to the /boot/grub/grub.cfg and open this file for editing.

Also running sudo grub-update will find your windows bootloader for win 10 and install it's entry.

Comment: I clarified my post, I don't plan to run linux on the system, just use a liveCD CLI to install it to MBR.